# App Engine Blobstore download all blobs at once

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I would like to download all blobs as a single zipped file (or another way) to my computer. Anyway to do that? I use the python SDK.

Comment: If I have 1000 large (~20MB each) blobs, how would the BlobReader Class help me download all of them. Of course it's not possible to put even a few of them in memory so what is your suggestion?

Comment: What are you trying to optimize for? Total download time?

Comment: Mostly download time then CPU after that, did you have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [request deadline](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#The_Request_Timer) of 60 seconds for each web request sent to GAE. [One request](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html) cannot have a response larger than 32 megs, nor can its handler generally use more than 128 megs of memory using the default quotas.

So hypothetically, if you have a very small application, *maybe* you could assemble a zip in-memory of all your blobs. But that's not going to be scalable, and if your blostore is so small anyway, is it worth it? (No, it isn't).

Bottom line is, very little in GAE is done all-at-once. You do things iteratively, over multiple requests.

Comment: the response size limit being 32meg kills the whole issue in it's tracks.

Answer (score 5):

No, there's no way to do this. The blobstore can be aribrarily large, far larger than is practical to download in a single file.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to download them one at a time anyway. That way if your job dies part way through you can restart for where it failed rather than starting over again from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

How about copy the blobs to google storage and then use gsutil to download the blobs from there?